# Pulsar-Functions on existing messages

Tags: apache-pulsar, pulsar

I am new to Apache Pulsar but I'm trying to use Pulsar-Functions to process existing messages on a topic.
It seems that these functions are intended for streaming purposes only, so they would only get triggered when new messages arrive to the input topic. Still, I wanted to confirm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes your guess is right.

To go back on the topic to a given time and read past data you need to use indexes manually.
Basically search for the message id and read from there using the Reader interface.

Consider also that you can write a consumer consuming from the start of the topic (you cannot use the function interface and runtime).